# Add a button on top of a Listview item that slides in from left (with animation)

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview of items and I want three buttons to slide in from the right side of the screen when one of those items is pressed. Here is an example:

the listview item if it hasn't been clicked:
[image]

the listview item if it has been clicked:
[image]

I'm also interested in "dimming" the project that has been selected via a translucent gray overlay. Is this possible? What is the best way to approach doing this? I have been doing research but everything seems to be gesture oriented and is more about removing items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sliding in the buttons shouldn't be too difficult. What you need to do is wrap them in a parent container (say, a horizontal `LinearLayout`). Set the visibility of the parent container to `android:visibility="invisible"`. Then, in your code, set the `OnClickListener` for your `ListView` item to start a Transition animation on the parent container you created that slides it from left to right. Be sure to set the parent container's visibility is set back to "visible" when you start the animation (for instance, inside your `onAnimationStart()` method inside an `AnimationListener` attached to the Animation in your code).

The animation can be stored in XML and look something like this:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">

  <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
             android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
             android:duration="400"/>
</set>
```

This obviously isn't everything you need, but hopefully it will help point you in the right direction. As far as dimming, I've done this before by overlaying the whole item view with a basic `View` that has a semi-transparent background color (like #88ffffff). Keep its visibility set to "gone" until you need to render the item as dimmed.

**Edit:** Here's what the translate animation may look inside your click listener:

```
TranslateAnimation translateAnim = (TranslateAnimation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.your_slide_in_animation);
translateAnim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
translateAnim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        buttonParentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
    });

buttonParentView.startAnimation(translateAnim);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am going to start working on this approach right now.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how I need to go about initiating the transition inside the onClickListener?